# Docker precheck error "code E_FAIL(0x80004005)"

Tags: docker

I started to study docker few days ago. And I had successfully created the virtual machine.But then came a problem. `VBoxManage.exe` throws the error to me.

```
VBoxManage.exe:error:Details:code E_FAIL(0x80004005),component MachineWrap,interface IMachine
```

Then I tried to reinstall the VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox, but the problem is still there. How can I run docker?
This is log's content.

```
1395c.ab88: Log file opened: 5.1.14r112924 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000070 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa0383900
1395c.ab88: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
1395c.ab88:     CreationTime:    2016-12-11T05:42:40.625928500Z
1395c.ab88:     LastWriteTime:   2016-11-11T10:13:03.409595100Z
1395c.ab88:     ChangeTime:      2017-02-14T11:21:25.305374800Z
1395c.ab88:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1395c.ab88:     Size:            0x1cc888
1395c.ab88:     NT Headers:      0xd8
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x5825887f
1395c.ab88:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x5825887f
1395c.ab88:     Image Version:   10.0
1395c.ab88:     SizeOfImage:     0x1d1000 (1904640)
1395c.ab88:     Resource Dir:    0x168000 LB 0x67988
1395c.ab88:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1395c.ab88:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.479
1395c.ab88:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.479 (rs1_release.161110-2025)
1395c.ab88:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
1395c.ab88: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
1395c.ab88:     CreationTime:    2016-07-16T11:42:16.155721400Z
1395c.ab88:     LastWriteTime:   2016-07-16T11:42:16.155721400Z
1395c.ab88:     ChangeTime:      2016-10-08T14:22:29.502949900Z
1395c.ab88:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1395c.ab88:     Size:            0xaade8
1395c.ab88:     NT Headers:      0xf0
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x57899a29
1395c.ab88:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x57899a29
1395c.ab88:     Image Version:   10.0
1395c.ab88:     SizeOfImage:     0xab000 (700416)
1395c.ab88:     Resource Dir:    0xa9000 LB 0x528
1395c.ab88:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1395c.ab88:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.0
1395c.ab88:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)
1395c.ab88:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1395c.ab88: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
1395c.ab88:     CreationTime:    2016-12-11T05:40:58.037837700Z
1395c.ab88:     LastWriteTime:   2016-11-11T10:13:54.529597600Z
1395c.ab88:     ChangeTime:      2017-02-14T11:21:25.150221200Z
1395c.ab88:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1395c.ab88:     Size:            0x21c780
1395c.ab88:     NT Headers:      0xf8
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x582588e6
1395c.ab88:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x582588e6
1395c.ab88:     Image Version:   10.0
1395c.ab88:     SizeOfImage:     0x21d000 (2215936)
1395c.ab88:     Resource Dir:    0x201000 LB 0x550
1395c.ab88:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1395c.ab88:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.479
1395c.ab88:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.479 (rs1_release.161110-2025)
1395c.ab88:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1395c.ab88: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
1395c.ab88:     CreationTime:    2016-07-16T11:42:21.577586000Z
1395c.ab88:     LastWriteTime:   2016-07-16T11:42:21.577586000Z
1395c.ab88:     ChangeTime:      2016-10-08T14:22:23.627373900Z
1395c.ab88:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1395c.ab88:     Size:            0x18960
1395c.ab88:     NT Headers:      0xc8
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x57899bd2
1395c.ab88:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1395c.ab88:     Timestamp:       0x57899bd2
1395c.ab88:     Image Version:   10.0
1395c.ab88:     SizeOfImage:     0x19000 (102400)
1395c.ab88:     Resource Dir:    0x18000 LB 0x400
1395c.ab88:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
1395c.ab88:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.0
1395c.ab88:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)
1395c.ab88:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
1395c.ab88: NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1395c.ab88: Calling main()
1395c.ab88: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
1395c.ab88: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
1395c.ab88: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32
1395c.ab88: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\WinSxS
1395c.ab88: KnownDllPath: C:\WINDOWS\System32
1395c.ab88: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1395c.ab88: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007fff6e3c9fa0 pvNtTerminateThread=00007fff6e3f6b20
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 14a64.12040 [kernel32].
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=00000000008cd000 cbPeb=0x388
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=00007fff6e350000 uNtDllChildAddr=00007fff6e350000
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=00007fff6e3c9fa0
1395c.ab88: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 3 ms.
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 263 ms, 30 sleeps
1395c.ab88: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1395c.ab88:  *0000000000000000-ffffffffff99ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *0000000000660000-000000000063ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:  *0000000000680000-0000000000669fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1395c.ab88:   0000000000696000-000000000068bfff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00000000006a0000-00000000005a4fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   000000000079b000-0000000000797fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   000000000079e000-000000000079bfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:  *00000000007a0000-000000000079bfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1395c.ab88:   00000000007a4000-0000000000797fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00000000007b0000-00000000007adfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   00000000007b2000-0000000000763fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *0000000000800000-0000000000732fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   00000000008cd000-00000000008c9fff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   00000000008d0000-000000000079ffff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   0000000000a00000-ffffffff8141ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1395c.ab88:   000000007fff0000-ffff800ac8b1ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00007ff6374c0000-00007ff63748cfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6374f3000-00007ff6368c5fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00007ff638120000-00007ff638120fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff638121000-00007ff63818ffff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff638190000-00007ff638190fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff638191000-00007ff6381d5fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381d6000-00007ff6381d6fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381d7000-00007ff6381d7fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381d8000-00007ff6381dcfff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381dd000-00007ff6381ddfff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381de000-00007ff6381defff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381df000-00007ff6381e2fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff6381e3000-00007ff63822afff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88:   00007ff63822b000-00007fed02105fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00007fff6e350000-00007fff6e350fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e351000-00007fff6e457fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e458000-00007fff6e49bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e49c000-00007fff6e4a4fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e4a5000-00007fff6e4b2fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e4b3000-00007fff6e4b3fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e4b4000-00007fff6e4b6fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e4b7000-00007fff6e520fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1395c.ab88:   00007fff6e521000-00007ffedca61fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1395c.ab88:  *00007ffffffe0000-00007ffffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
1395c.ab88: VBoxHeadless.exe: timestamp 0x587cf70b (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1395c.ab88: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1395c.ab88: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 303 ms and 0 fixes (loop #0).
14a64.12040: Log file opened: 5.1.14r112924 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000008 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa0383900
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=00007fff6e350000 g_uNtVerCombined=0xa0383900
14a64.12040: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x5825887f (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
14a64.12040: New simple heap: #1 0000000000b00000 LB 0x400000 (for 1904640 allocation)
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
14a64.12040: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32
14a64.12040: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\WinSxS
14a64.12040: KnownDllPath: C:\WINDOWS\System32
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
14a64.12040: Registered Dll notification callback with NTDLL.
14a64.12040: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll)
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (Input=KERNEL32.DLL, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000004001:<flags> [calling]
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007fff6aa80000 LB 0x0021d000 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll [fFlags=0x0]
14a64.12040: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll)
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007fff6b890000 LB 0x000ab000 C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL [fFlags=0x0]
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007fff6b890000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL'
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff638120000 LB 0x0010b000 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe [fFlags=0x0]
14a64.12040: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
14a64.12040: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 1 (CloseEvents) after 117 ms.
14a64.12040: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007fff6e3c9fa0 pvNtTerminateThread=00007fff6e3f6b20
14a64.12040: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
14a64.12040:     CreationTime:    2016-12-11T05:42:40.625928500Z
14a64.12040:     LastWriteTime:   2016-11-11T10:13:03.409595100Z
14a64.12040:     ChangeTime:      2017-02-14T11:21:25.305374800Z
14a64.12040:     FileAttributes:  0x20
14a64.12040:     Size:            0x1cc888
14a64.12040:     NT Headers:      0xd8
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x5825887f
14a64.12040:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x5825887f
14a64.12040:     Image Version:   10.0
14a64.12040:     SizeOfImage:     0x1d1000 (1904640)
14a64.12040:     Resource Dir:    0x168000 LB 0x67988
14a64.12040:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
14a64.12040:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.479
14a64.12040:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.479 (rs1_release.161110-2025)
14a64.12040:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
14a64.12040: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
14a64.12040:     CreationTime:    2016-07-16T11:42:16.155721400Z
14a64.12040:     LastWriteTime:   2016-07-16T11:42:16.155721400Z
14a64.12040:     ChangeTime:      2016-10-08T14:22:29.502949900Z
14a64.12040:     FileAttributes:  0x20
14a64.12040:     Size:            0xaade8
14a64.12040:     NT Headers:      0xf0
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x57899a29
14a64.12040:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x57899a29
14a64.12040:     Image Version:   10.0
14a64.12040:     SizeOfImage:     0xab000 (700416)
14a64.12040:     Resource Dir:    0xa9000 LB 0x528
14a64.12040:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
14a64.12040:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.0
14a64.12040:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)
14a64.12040:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
14a64.12040: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
14a64.12040:     CreationTime:    2016-12-11T05:40:58.037837700Z
14a64.12040:     LastWriteTime:   2016-11-11T10:13:54.529597600Z
14a64.12040:     ChangeTime:      2017-02-14T11:21:25.150221200Z
14a64.12040:     FileAttributes:  0x20
14a64.12040:     Size:            0x21c780
14a64.12040:     NT Headers:      0xf8
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x582588e6
14a64.12040:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x582588e6
14a64.12040:     Image Version:   10.0
14a64.12040:     SizeOfImage:     0x21d000 (2215936)
14a64.12040:     Resource Dir:    0x201000 LB 0x550
14a64.12040:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
14a64.12040:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.479
14a64.12040:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.479 (rs1_release.161110-2025)
14a64.12040:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
14a64.12040: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
14a64.12040:     CreationTime:    2016-07-16T11:42:21.577586000Z
14a64.12040:     LastWriteTime:   2016-07-16T11:42:21.577586000Z
14a64.12040:     ChangeTime:      2016-10-08T14:22:23.627373900Z
14a64.12040:     FileAttributes:  0x20
14a64.12040:     Size:            0x18960
14a64.12040:     NT Headers:      0xc8
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x57899bd2
14a64.12040:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
14a64.12040:     Timestamp:       0x57899bd2
14a64.12040:     Image Version:   10.0
14a64.12040:     SizeOfImage:     0x19000 (102400)
14a64.12040:     Resource Dir:    0x18000 LB 0x400
14a64.12040:     ProductName:     Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
14a64.12040:     ProductVersion:  10.0.14393.0
14a64.12040:     FileVersion:     10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)
14a64.12040:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
14a64.12040: NtOpenDirectoryObject failed on \Driver: 0xc0000022
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
14a64.12040: Calling main()
14a64.12040: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0
14a64.12040: supR3HardenedWinInitAppBin(0x0): '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox'
14a64.12040: '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
14a64.12040: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
14a64.12040: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #2
14a64.12040: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
14a64.12040: Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5)
14a64.12040: Error relaunching VirtualBox VM process: 5
Command line: '60eaff78-4bdd-042d-2e72-669728efd737-suplib-3rdchild --comment default --startvm 2f777a23-278b-43d7-bc83-4159fd4cd54e --vrde config --sup-hardening-log=C:\Users\defaultuser0\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'
1395c.ab88: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 58 ms, the end);
```

`

Comment: That seems to be an error in VirtualBox itself. Have you tried to look at the virtualbox logs? (search for a .virtualbox folder in your user home folder)

Comment: I can't read Virtual Box's log...It's too hard to read... but I can show you the log's content.

Comment: Let us know your host o.s. and virtualbox version. Investigate about Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn you get in the log file.

Comment: But.....I updated my os to Windows 10.And I'm using Docker for windows now.

Comment: How can i close this question?